# Битрикс - дочернее меню, где править шаблон вывода меню?

Tags: php, битрикс

Имеется такое меню

```
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
                "bitrix:menu",
                "tree",
                Array(
                    "ROOT_MENU_TYPE" => "top",
                    "MENU_CACHE_TYPE" => "N",
                    "MENU_CACHE_TIME" => "3600",
                    "MENU_CACHE_USE_GROUPS" => "Y",
                    "MENU_CACHE_GET_VARS" => array(""),
                    "MAX_LEVEL" => "2",
                    "CHILD_MENU_TYPE" => "dopmenu",
                    "USE_EXT" => "Y",
                    "DELAY" => "N",
                    "ALLOW_MULTI_SELECT" => "N",
                    "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => "tree"
                )
            );?>
```

Дело в том что оно формирует html такого вида, то есть без указания какой пункт меню активен и еще шлака накидывает, где это можно исправить или какой шаблон человеческий есть в этой cms

```
    <div class="menu-sitemap-tree">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="page"></div>
            <div class="item-text"><a href="/parent1/">Родитель1</a></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="folder" onclick="OpenMenuNode(this)"></div>
            <div class="item-text"><a href="/parent2/">Родитель2</a></div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="page"></div>
                    <div class="item-text"><a href="/parent2/son1/">Сынок1</a></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="page"></div>
                    <div class="item-text"><a href="/parent2/son1/">Сынок2</a></div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="page"></div>
            <div class="item-text"><a href="/novosti/">Новости</a></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="page"></div>
            <div class="item-text"><a href="/aktsii/">Акции</a></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="page"></div>
            <div class="item-text"><a href="/voprosy-i-otvety/">Вопросы и ответы</a></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="page"></div>
            <div class="item-text"><a href="/kontakty/">Контакты</a></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Вот же у вас указан шаблон - `tree`

Comment: @u_mulder а где его файл лежит или как создать свой

Comment: Ёмоё, это же базовые понятия и гуглится на раз. http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=2829

Answer (score 1):

Ваш шаблон лежит (по умолчанию) в папке `bitrix->components->bitrix->bitrix:menu->temlates->tree`. Сам файл шаблона называется `template.php`.

Comment: Я разобрался нужно было в шаблоне сделать такую же структуру как в компонентах, потом скопировать туда шаблон и переписать вывод меню